# Why does FROM_UNIXTIME is returning date back in 1970?

Tags: mysql, intervals

I am trying to get the interval between 2 date.

If I have '2014-10-31' and '2014-10-10' then results needs to be '2014-10-21'

Here is what I have done.

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(unix_timestamp(CURDATE()) - unix_timestamp('2014-10-10'), '%Y-%m-%d')
```

But this is returning 
1970-01-22

What I want it to return is 2014-10-21

Why is it not working? and how to get the answer that I am looking for?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Sorry about my answer, I went too fast. Now I notice that you're trying to get a date from a unix time which is the result of a substraction of 2 unix timestamps. The result cannot be what you expect.

Comment: What does it mean to subtract one date from another and get back a date?  Why should subtracting '2014-10-10' from '2014-10-31' give a date? Do you want a number of days between the dates? Could you please consider clarifyng your question?

Comment: The difference between two closely related timestamps in seconds is going to be treated as 1970-01-01 00:00:00 plus that many seconds, and is usually going to be a date in 1970.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The result of `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` is - you might have guessed - a UNIX timestamp: An integer starting with 0 at 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC and counting one for every second since. The important part is, that zero on this timescale is neither 0 A.D. nor some other historic event, but Jan 1st, 1970.

Your example, `unix_timestamp(CURDATE()) - unix_timestamp('2014-10-10')` calculates a difference of 21 days (as of your posting time) - this translates to a date of 1970-01-01 + 21 days, resulting in 1970-01-22.

**EDIT**

As from @Mike's question in the comments: Subtracting two dates gives a timespan, not a date. To interpret this as a date again, you need to add it to some starting point in time. As seen above, the UNIX timestamp uses 1970-01-01, while the gregorian calendar uses a ficitve year of Christ's birth. To use this, you would take

```
DATE_ADD('0001-01-01', INTERVAL (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE()) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-10-10')) SECOND)
```

resulting in the correct value of `0001-01-22`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Any idea on how to subtract 2 dates and get the answer in a date format?

Comment: @Mike: the result is an interval, not a date.